# Locating elements of non angular iframe using protractor's switchTo

Tags: angularjs, webdriver, protractor

I have an angularjs app containing an iframe that display the page allowing to log into another website. I am trying to put some value in the fields contained in the iframe but I can't find the elements using any locator.

Here is my test :

```
describe("Harvest", function() {

  beforeEach(function () {

browser.get('http://localhost:8110/');

expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch('_*#/login$');

element(by.model('user.username')).sendKeys('sam');
element(by.model('user.password')).sendKeys('pass');

element(by.id('bt_signin')).click();

  });

  afterEach(function () {
    browser.executeScript('window.sessionStorage.clear();');
  });

  describe('A user', function () {

beforeEach(function () {
  browser.get('http://localhost:8110/');
});

it('should be able to obtain an access token from harvest', function () {
  expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch('_*#/home$');

  //Display and close the window
  element(by.id('btHarvest')).click();

  expect(element(by.id('modalHarvest')).isPresent()).toBe(true);

  element(by.id('btCloseModal')).click();

  expect(element(by.id('modalHarvest')).isPresent()).toBe(false);

  //Authenticate into harvest
  element(by.id('btHarvest')).click();

  expect(element(by.id('modalHarvest')).isPresent()).toBe(true);

  browser.switchTo().frame('iframeHarvest');

  //It fails here with a null exceptions, guess it can't find it
  element(by.id('email')).sendKeys(browser.params.harvestLogins.user);
  element(by.id('user_password')).sendKeys(browser.params.harvestLogins.password);
  element(by.id('sign-in-button')).click();

  expect(element(by.name('commit')).isPresent()).toBe(true);

  browser.driver.switchTo().defaultContent();



});

});

});
```

And here is the exception generated

```
1) Harvest A user should be able to obtain an access token from harvest
   Message:
     [31mError: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: {}[0m
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: {}
    at Error (<anonymous>)
==== async task ====
WebDriver.executeScript()
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/samdurand/workspace/cake/subbie/src/test/web/js/features/harvest.js:45:22)
==== async task ====
Asynchronous test function: it()
Error
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/samdurand/workspace/cake/subbie/src/test/web/js/features/harvest.js:26:5)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/samdurand/workspace/cake/subbie/src/test/web/js/features/harvest.js:20:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/samdurand/workspace/cake/subbie/src/test/web/js/features/harvest.js:1:63)
```

After correcting the iframe call as suggested I get this error :

```
1) Projects A user is possible to create a project based on harvest data
   Message:
     [31mError: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: {}[0m
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: {}
    at Error (<anonymous>)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed, the issue that you are facing is because the `iframe` that you are switching to is non-angular. Thus, `element(by.id)` will not work after you switch to that `iframe`. Instead, `findElement` needs to be used!

Comment: The first correction you made me do changed the error to something I should have recognised. It could not sync because it was not an angular app. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Since yours is an Angular Application, could you please try using:

```
browser.switchTo().frame('iframeHarvest');
```

instead of:

```
browser.driver.switchTo().frame(element(by.id('iframeHarvest')));
```

Comment: You are right I should have use that from the beginning because it is an angularJS app, however it doesn't solve my problem. I still get an error. But I found a solution thought I don't understand why it is working in this case and not with my previous code.

Comment: 1 edit: switchTo has the following syntax:
browser.switchTo().frame(<frameName>) -- http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp
browser.switchTo().frame('iframeHarvest');   Please try and let know if it helps!

Comment: Your syntax is working. it's suprising I didn't see it anywhere else before, however it still doesn't solve the problem of the 'element()' instruction not working

Comment: I didn't notice before but the error evolved ! now it is   as in the edit

Comment: Did you change the browser.driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); to browser.switchTo().defaultContent();

Comment: the thing is that it fails immediately after the switchto, when I try to do the first expect, but you are right I will change the other switchto anyway. It doesn't affect the result thought because it not called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63577/discussion-between-sakshi-singla-and-sam).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but I still wait for an explanation from the angular team, because I don't understand why using `element` fails but using the driver directly succeed. Here is the code that works (I included the suggestion from @Sakshi even thought it doesn't change the result) :

```
browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.id('iframeHarvest')));
browser.driver.findElement(by.id('email')).sendKeys(browser.params.harvestLogins.user);
```

edit : here is the protractor subject https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1465